# How can I access "http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations" using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest, basic-authentication

I am trying to access the XML http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations using ASIHTTPRequest. But what I am using now doesn't seem to work. It says the host is not reachable. So I assume it is going wrong at the ASIHTTPRequest part?

```
-(void)fetchStationData {
//Method for the fetching of the data

//First lets check wheater there is an internet connection and if the host is reachable
if(internetActive) {

    //Internet is active

    //Init the parser
    parser = [[RSSParser alloc] init];

    //Set he parser context
    parser.context = context;

    //The array to het the data from 


     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations"];
     ASIHTTPRequest *requestaccount = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [requestaccount setUsername:@"user"];
     [requestaccount setPassword:@"password"];
    //The XML elements to fetch
    NSArray *elements = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name",nil];
    //The actual fetchin
    [parser fetchStationItemsForUrl:url forElements:elements];

    //Save the context ?
    [context save:nil];

    //Clean up
    [elements release]; 

}else{

    //Internet is down  :( 
    //Offline artikelen inladen

    //Dit uitvoeren op de main que
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

        UIAlertView *Notpermitted = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Er is geen verbinding mogelijk met de Mezz. Offline artikelen zijn ingeladen." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [Notpermitted show];
        [Notpermitted release];

    });

}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information on the error you are receiving? (if any?) What is the expected result, and what is the result you get? Do you have more code? (this does not even include the [request startSynchronous]; or [request startAsynchronous]; calls) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ASIFormDataRequest`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"accountname" forKey:@"username"];
[request addPostValue:@"password" forKey:@"password"];

[request setCompletionBlock:^ {
  // do something when request succeeds and credentials are ok, e.g. redirect user to the home page
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^ {
  // notify user that request failed
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I am using this now. But I do get a few warnings now and it still says the host in reachable. This is the warning I get: Local declaration of 'request' hides instance variable.

Comment: Which means you've got a "request" variable somewhere in your .h or .m file declared. Simply change the request name to something like "authRequest" for this function. You also have to be 100% sure what names does your Server takes via POST request, if they're not "username" and "password" then change them to appropriate.

Comment: these warnings are fixed now and I changed the accountname and password to Gebruikersnaam and Wachtwoord as the http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations asks for. But it still says the host is not not reachable.

Comment: It runs the [request setFailedBlock:^ {
}];
I tested it with a NSlog

Comment: replace [request setFailedBlock:^ { }]; with [request setFailedBlock:^ { NSLog(@"Cause: %@. Code: %d", request.error.localizedDescription, request.error.code); }]; it will point out why request fails

Comment: 2011-11-06 17:04:56.113 OV app[3279:fb03] Cause: Authentication needed. Code: 3    it says authentication needed but I did fill in my account. And I am certain my account info is right because I am able to login in with safari.

Comment: You should consult your webmaster about how exactly you must authorize via direct request. You might need to set up Authorization: header or your variables aren't named properly.

Comment: my variables where not named properly webmaster mailed me thank you.